# How can I seralilze a value in C# to store in a mySql database that WordPress can deserialize?

Tags: c#, mysql, wordpress, serialization

I'm building an app that updates a WordPress database; WordPress stores serialized values in some of its fields. I need to serialize values and store them in WordPress so that WordPress can still deserialize them as normal, as if the data was entered directly in WordPress.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here's an example of a value stores as serialized data in mySql:
_voucherLocations = a:5:{i:0;s:3:"All";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";}

All I entered in the WordPress form was "All"
When someone enters "All" in my WinForms form, it has to be stored the same way as seen above in the mySql database so the theme I'm using in WordPress recognizes it and can use it.  Hope this is clear.

I'm using C# with Entity Framework 5 and the latest mySQL Data Adapater provided by Microsoft in a WinForms app. BTW if anyone does this and gets exceptions when trying to do any insert, update or delete operations, it's because Entity Framework changes the identity integer in mySQL to an unasigned decimal; I had to manually go in the entire Entity Framework generated code and change all those wrong data declarations into bigint from unsigned decimal.  Just a heads up for anyone trying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has special function [to serialize and deserialize data](http://php.net/serialize), it is not JSON. I know only one library which can serialize and deserialize this data in .NET: [csphpserial](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csphpserial/)

Comment: Fantastic -- csphpserial is formatting this correctly.  It seems to be wrapping the result in another array. 

Example:
a:5:{i:0;s:3:"All";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";}
and deserialize it using csphpserial , it returns "All" But a 5-element arraylist with "All" in the first item and "" in the other 4, serialized gets the same result shown above but it appends this in front (with the last bracket at the end though) a:1:{s:0:"";}  So the result looks like this: a:1:{s:0:"";a:5:{i:0;s:3:"All";i:1;s:0:"";i:2;s:0:"";i:3;s:0:"";i:4;s:0:"";}} Any idea how to get rid of the extra bit?

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of one of the JSON libraries for this. A popular one that ships with ASP.NET MVC is [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) and is available as a NuGet packe for install as below:

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

You may also try another library which is gaining popularity, [ServiceStack Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text):

```
PM> Install-Package ServiceStack.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's just JSON serialization. You should be able to do that easily in C#.

Have a look at [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)